# Relational Algebra using aggregate functions?

Tags: sql, database, aggregate, aggregate-functions, relational-algebra

I have written a couple of queries using aggregate functions and since I cannot check them using winRDBI, I would like to ask if I did them correctly?

Below is the database schema:

```
Author - (authorNum/numeric, authorLast/char, authorFirst/char) PK: authorNum

Book - (bookCode/char, title/char, publisherCode/char, type/char, 
       price/numeric, paperback/char) PK: bookCode

Branch - (branchNum/numeric, branchName/char, branchLocation/char, numEmployees/numeric) PK: branchNum

Inventory - (bookCode/char, branchNum/numeric, onHand/numeric) PK: bookCode

Publisher - (publisherCode/char, publisherName/char, city/char) PK: publisherCode

Wrote - (bookCode/char, authorNum/numeric, sequence/numeric) PK: bookCode,authorNum

Sequence refers to the sequence in which this author appears on the 
         cover – first author, second author, etc.

Copy - (bookCode/char, branchNum/numeric, copyNum/numeric, 
       quality/char, price/numeric) PK: bookCode, branchNum, copyNum
```

I don't think it is necessary but here is a PDF of the actual database I am working with : [Database PDF](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwoymYbIFmnyWkNzeXNDMnFuRDA)

Here are the queries with there respective answers (all statements that do no not use aggregate functions are written in winRDBI notation):

1) List the average price of all copies of books available at ‘Henry Downtown’ branch.

```
branch_names := copy njoin (project branchNum, branchName (branch));

in_Henry_Downtown :=  project bookCode, copyNum, price, branchName (select 
(branchName = 'Henry Downtown') (branch_names));

ans1 := bookCode g avg(price) (in_Henry_Book);
```

Snippet of the relation table `in_Henry_Downtown` : [in_Henry_Downtown](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwoymYbIFmnyZzJnaTI3TTRmVG8)

2) For every book that is possessed by Henry Books, output the book code, the number of total copies available collectively at all its branches, and the average price of a copy of that book.

```
in_stock1 := (project bookCode (book)) njoin (project bookCode, branchNum (inventory));

copies := in_stock1 njoin (project bookCode, branchNum, copyNum, price (copy));

ans2 := bookCode g count(branchNum, copyNum), avg(price) (copies);
```

Snippet of the relation table `copies` : [copies](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwoymYbIFmnyWk54TkdKWHpVYTA)

This is the one I am least sure about. I am trying to count the copies of books at all branches collectively. So, for book code '0200' the count should be 4, b/c branch #1 has copy #1 and copy #2 of this book and branch #2 has copy #1 and copy #2 of this book. My though process is that since branchNum and copyNum will be unique for each record of a specific bookCode then I can use those attributes for my count function.

3) For every publisher, list the name of the publisher, number of books it has published, and the average base price (Book relation contains the base price of a book) of those books.

```
publisher_books := (project publisherCode, publisherName (publisher)) 
        njoin (project bookCode, publisherCode,price (book));

ans3 := publisherName g count(bookCode), avg(price) (publisher_books);
```

Snippet of the relation table `publisher_books`: [publisher_books](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwoymYbIFmnyTENYbm9NTi1kWVU)

Any help will be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What does "since I cannot check them using winRDBI" mean? What is a reference to the version of "relational algebra" you are to use? PS Please only insert links via the SO interface. Also please don't include links necessary to the question, put content inline. Also please do not insert images that can be text.

Comment: winRDBI allows me to query a DB using relational algebra but does not support the use of aggregate functions.